# Optimization: Search the best way to compare two list of dict (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, hash, mapping

I need to optimize a function made in python who's check two list of dict and return the difference as a list.

### Explanation :

I have two list in input. Each list containing a series of `dict` formated like that :

```
{
    'a': 'foo',
    'b': 'bar',
    'switch': True
}
```

First, I have to check if the duo `a` and `b` found in the second list exist in the first, if not, I append the new duo in a list called **added**.
Same way, I have to check if the duo `a` and `b` found in the first list exist in the second, if not, I append the deleted duo in a list called **delisted**.

Then, I have to check beetween the existing duo in each list if the `switch` key are the same. If not I have I have to add this in a **switched** list.

### Exemple :

To resume this, here is an exemple :

```
# First list in input
first = [
    {
        'a': 'foo',
        'b': 'bar',
        'switch': False
    },{
        'a': 'I_will',
        'b': 'be_delisted',
        'switch': True
    },{
        'a': 'I_will',
        'b': 'be_switched',
        'switch': True
    }
]

# Second list to compare
second = [
    {
        'a': 'foo',
        'b': 'bar',
        'switch': False
    },{
        'a': 'I_am',
        'b': 'new',
        'switch': True
    },{
        'a': 'I_will',
        'b': 'be_switched',
        'switch': False # switched
    }
]

diff = my_diff(first, second)
```

Expected output:

```
{
    'added': [{
        'a': 'I_am',
        'b': 'new',
        'switch': True
    }],
    'delisted': [{
        'a': 'I_will',
        'b': 'be_delisted',
        'switch': True
    }],
    'switched': [{
        'a': 'I_will',
        'b': 'be_switched',
        'switch': False
    }]
}
```

So there is two *distinct comparison* :

- comparison of element between list
- comparison of the content of the same existing element

### Existing code :

To do the first comparison between list I use the `hash` function to make a hash of the duo for the comparison. Then, I add this hash in a **first_hash** list and **second_hash** list with the index of each element.

Like that :

```
first_hash = [ ( hash((first[i]['a'], first[i]['b'])), i ) for i in xrange(0, len(first))]
second_hash = [ ( hash((second[i]['a'], second[i]['b'])), i ) for i in xrange(0, len(second))]
```

I get my added and delisted list :

```
added = [ second[ e[1] ] for e in second_hash if e[0] not in (fh[0] for fh in first_hash) ]
delisted = [ first[ e[1] ] for e in first_hash if e[0] not in (sh[0] for sh in second_hash) ]
```

I get the same element of the two list and I push these element in a dict with the hash in key to easy compare it :

```
sames_first = [ (e[0], first[ e[1] ]) for e in first_hash if e[0] in (sh[0] for sh in second_hash) ] # Getting the seconds same elements
sames_second = [ (e[0], second[ e[1] ]) for e in second_hash if e[0] in (fh[0] for fh in first_hash) ] # Getting the first same elements

sfirst = {}
ssecond = {}

for sf in sames_first:
    sfirst[sf[0]] = sf[1]

for ss in sames_second:
    ssecond[ss[0]] = ss[1]
```

Then, I compare and get the switched list :

```
switched = [ssecond[e] for e in ssecond.keys() if ssecond[e]['switch'] != sfirst[e]['switch']]
```

> I push the copy `ssecond[e]` (the element of the second list) to have the new value.

### Complete Code :

- With a tester in pastebin to test in local : [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/G6PDwaA3)
- Test directly online : [Online testing](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMOUh2NWdiS0E0Qmc)

Actually I get :

```
1.92713737488 ms for 100 element
162.150144577 ms for 1000 element
15205.0578594 ms for 10000 element
```

My question is : **Is there a more efficient way to do this task on a large data set ?**
(*Like mapping the object or his index and one of is attribute and directly compare them ?*)

Thanks to anyone who will take a little of his time to read and try to respond to my request :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have the output format in a dict. Using list comprehension you can get the desired output with a more reasonable time complexity.

```
    [res['switched'].append(i) if switchDict(i) in first else res['added'].append(i) if i not in first  else None for i in second ]
```

the above populates the switched(if the element is found as a switched on in first) and  added(if the element is not present in first) key of your res dict.

```
res['delisted']=[i for i in first if i not in second and switchDict(i) not in res['switched']]
```

Similarly,populate delisted key of res list with the condition iterating first list by checking the condition if it isnt present in second and is not in a switched.

**EDIT** made was  -  checking `switchDict(i) not in res['switched']` instead of `switchDict(i) not in second` in the above snippet, to reduce the execution time by 500ms(approx) for 10000 elements!

Therefore,

```
def switchDict(d):
    return {'a':d['a'],'b':d['b'],'switch':not d['switch']}

def my_diff(first, second):
    res = dict.fromkeys(['added','switched','delisted'],[]) # to make things more pythonic!
    second = filter(None,[res['switched'].append(i) if switchDict(i) in first else res['added'].append(i) if i not in first  else i for i in second ]) 
    # filtering the missing elements alone that may not be delisted as storing it as second
    #thereby reducing the execution time by another 1000ms(approx)
    res['delisted']=[i for i in first if i not in second and switchDict(i) not in res['switched']]
    return res
```

Will  give you the appropriate results in

```
0.0457763671875 ms for 10 element
1.32894515991 ms for 100 element
64.845085144 ms for 1000 element
6941.58291817 ms for 10000 element
```

(The time here depends on the random input generated from the python file you've shared!)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yeah, I got `8677.22296715 ms for 10000 element` this is clearly more efficient ! Thanks

Comment: Got `6831.35819435 ms for 10000 element` with your update ! Thanks you

Comment: Yeah. It varies with the random input! :)

Answer (score 0):

I found an other solution with hashing element :

```
def hash_elem(e):
    return hash( ( e['a'], e['b'] ) )

def my_diff(first, second):
    res = {'added':[],'switched':[],'delisted':[]}

    hf = {}
    hs = {}

    for ef in first:
        hf[hash_elem(ef)] = ef
    for es in second:
        hs[hash_elem(es)] = es

    sames = [s for s in hs.keys() if s in hf.keys()]
    [res['switched'].append(hs[s]) for s in sames if hs[s]['switch'] != hf[s]['switch']]

    [res['added'].append(hs[a]) for a in hs.keys() if a not in hf.keys()]
    [res['delisted'].append(hf[a]) for a in hf.keys() if a not in hs.keys()]

    return res
```

I got :

```
0.0219345092773 ms for 10 element
0.480175018311 ms for 100 element
38.6848449707 ms for 1000 element
6074.10311699 ms for 10000 element
```

I'm trying to mix this with your solution Keerthana Prabhakaran.

Comment: Good try. Glad that it helped! But your method take longer time for 10000 elements test case that is `0.0400543212891 ms for 10 element`,
 `1.11699104309 ms for 100 element`,
 `46.4980602264 ms for 1000 element`,
 `7915.52495956 ms for 10000 element` . I've added an edit to my answer reducing the time by another 1000ms!

Comment: I have to try this in production environment, because I get  better results on my computer with this solution yet. I notice you the results of your solution :) !

Comment: Cool! Happy Coding!